# Notification - Customizar Actions

Tags: android, android-notification

Gostaria de saber se é possível customizar um Notification com suas Actions.

Exemplo:

```
RemoteViews remoteViews = new RemoteViews(getPackageName(), R.layout.customnotification);
Notification.Builder builder = new Notification.Builder(this) 
        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_ico)
        .setAutoCancel(true) 
        .setContentIntent(pIntent) 
        .setContent(remoteViews)
        .addAction(R.drawable.ic_sim, "Sim", intent)
        .addAction(R.drawable.ic_nao, "Não", outraIntent);
```

Quando removo o `.addAction`, ele carrega corretamente o content.

Mas quando incluo, ele exibe o layout padrão da Notification.

Desde já agradeço!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como você está utilizar uma *custom view* como *layout* da notificação, em vez de usar `addAction()`, o seu *layout* deverá disponibilizar botões que, quando clicados, executarão as *actions*.

Os *intent's* `intent` e `outraIntent` são atribuídos a esses botões da seguinte forma:

```
remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.button1, intent);
remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.button2, outraIntent);
```

Ver [RemoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RemoteViews.html#setOnClickPendingIntent%28int,%20android.app.PendingIntent%29)

Comment: Funcionou corretamente ! Muito Obrigado!